# Can I charge 1 cell Li-ion battery with a charger for 2 cells?

Tags: lithium-ion, charger

I'm designing a battery charger using  monolithic step-down battery
charger that operates over a 4.95V to 32V input
voltage range.

On the datasheet I found a typical schematic for 2 cells but using just 1 cell Li-ion battery.
Do you know if using the typical design for 2 cells I can charge my 1 cell battery? Or do I have to change anything?

Comment: Probably not. What does the datasheet say?

Comment: I'm using the LT 3652 and it says the typical design for charge 2 cells li-ion batteries

Comment: Can you set the termination voltage?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the 542K and 459k resistors in their typical application diagram shown [here.](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/3652fe.pdf)

Page 7 shows the formula, and a quick calculation on my end suggests 272k for R1 and 3M for R2 for a float voltage of 3.6v (Assumes LiFePo4 chemistry)

Page 15 goes into details for another resistor configuration for a 3.6v cuttoff voltage using lower resistance values that may be easier to find high precision resistors for.